# how to handle dynamically created textview seprately in TextView Array?

Tags: android, arrays, loops, textview, dynamically-generated

how to handle dynamically created textview seprately in TextView Array?

I have Textview Array in which I add Textview Dynamically. If I have 3 textviews created using loop. so how can I change the text of first textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index of your array to access your desired TextView reference, then modify that one.

So if your array has 3 elements and you would like to modify your first element you do:

```
// This assumes the name of your array is textViewArr
textViewArr[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener
{
   void onClick(View v)
   {
     // Perform Click Logic here.
   }
});
```

Comment: i want to set onclicklistner on a array of dynamically created textviews and then get the textview onclick

Comment: Updated my answer to set the click listener instead.